# Play a list of wav files using rh.FileReader

Tags: redhawksdr

I have multiple wav files I need to transmit through a waveform using rh.Filereader is there a way to have the rh.Filereader component play wave files from a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rh.FileReader` will attempt to read all files in a directory when the `source_uri` is set to a directory path. For a directory of wav files, also configure the `file_format` to `WAV`. The header of the wav file is used to determine sample rate, so you do not need to configure that property. The list of files that will be read, and the order in which they will be read, is available by querying the `file_status` property. Note that `rh.FileReader` does not sort the list of files, so this feature may be of limited use if the files must be read in a certain order.